# Unable to import org module to PySpark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, fpgrowth

I am trying to import FPGrowth from org module but it throws an error while installing the org module. I also tried replacing org.apache.spark to pyspark, still doesn't work.

```
!pip install org
import org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth
```

below is the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement org (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for org
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c730562e7076> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install org')
----> 2 import org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import `FPGrowth` in PySpark you need to write:

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
```

You can find additional instructions on how to use `FPGrowth` in [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html).